# SKProductsResponse returning invalidProductIdentifiers on simulator inspite uniformity between the productId in application and iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

As a beginner whil trying in-app purchase in iOS application I followed the following steps :

1. enabled in app purchase in capabilities.
2. created provisional profile on developer account and downloaded
   it.
3. created iTunes Connect app submission.
4. created in-app purchase products in Features sections of iTunes
   Connect.[image: itunes screenshot]
5. created the same array of product identifiers. Also implemented required delegates in view controller class.

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
   @interface ViewController :UIViewController<SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver,SKRequestDelegate>
   ```

in viewdidload()

```
 productIds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pro1",@"pro2", nil];
```

also,

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
   if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
   SKProductsRequest *requestPro = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productIds]];
  requestPro.delegate = self;
  [requestPro start];
   }
   else{
    NSLog(@"Cannot perform In App Purchases.");
    }
    }
```

6. but -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response implementation is returning invalid products.

Please help me in understanding whats lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test most in app purchase related functions on a real device. They don't work on the simulator!